# How to group by week?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a report where I need the sum of UserHits by week, starting from the first week to the last week of a specific year.

How to achieve this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb181/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE UserData
(
DateCreated dateTime2 NOT NULL,
UserHits int NOT NULL
);

insert into UserData
values
('2014-01-01',100),
('2014-01-02',50),
('2014-01-03',20),
('2014-01-20',100),
('2014-01-21',100),
('2014-01-22',70),
('2014-02-02',100),
('2014-02-03',100);
```

Comment: _"How to achieve this in a faster way?"_ Faster than what? You haven't shown your approach. What is the difference between your question and the others on SO which ask for grouping by week?

Comment: Thanks for commenting I have just edit my question.

Comment: @GibboK you should fill out your information. At least where you are from. How week is defined is different from country to country. Personally I prefer ISO_WEEK. That is not what you get with datapart though. If you use are using ISOWEEK, a proper answer for your question will be quite extensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select  datepart(wk, DateCreated)
,       sum(UserHits)
from    UserData
group by
        datepart(wk, DateCreated)
```